# Knockout partial validation of viewmodel

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I am rather new to [KockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/)
But I have [this working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jphellemons/BkXpZ/21/) which validates.
But I would like to have a set of about 5 observables and validate that set.
It is meant as some sort of wizard and at each step a validation of the observables in that step.

I have read about `validatedObservable` but do I have to make a var for it outside the viewModel and then reference the observables in the viewmodel?
I found [this as only reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364788/knockout-validation-validatedobservable-group-error) and having difficulties understanding the grouping and validating with knockout validation.

Here is my JS code:

```
function ovm() {
    var self = this;
    this.delStreet = ko.observable("").extend( {required: true} );
    this.deliveryNotSameAsInvoice = ko.observable(false);
    this.invStreet = ko.observable('');
    this.delCountry = ko.observable("");
    var invStreetCheck = ko.computed(function(){
        var checked = self.deliveryNotSameAsInvoice(),
            delStreet = self.delStreet();
        if(!checked)
            return self.invStreet(delStreet);
        return self.invStreet();
    });
}

var vm = new ovm();
ko.applyBindings(vm);

$("#s1").click(function(){
    alert(vm.delStreet.isValid());
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's how I solved this problem for someone else](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16738317/1388818).

It uses ValidatedViewModel from Carl Schroed and allows you to choose which validation options you want to apply - extremely handy for multi-step forms.

Comment: Thanks I have read the comments and think that for my solution a clustered validatedobservable is better, but I have no idea how that works. because i don't want to have much logic in the viewmodel.

Comment: I've found Knockout had a really steep learning curve for me so I know how it feels.

I suggest having a play with the fiddle I created and see how you get on with it: http://jsfiddle.net/79IT/aYb6t/26/

Comment: Thanks for that jsfiddle. I had this one with the validatedobservable http://jsfiddle.net/jphellemons/BkXpZ/23/ But I will definitely look at your jsfiddle! thanks!